# How to run multiple jobs with spring quartz and the jobs are feched from database

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

How to run multiple jobs with spring quartz and the jobs are feched from database.

Please provide any example code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can start by reading the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) and [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson09.html).  If you then have a more specific question, then come back and ask it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to this question:

1. How to run Quartz.
2. How to connect to a database.
3. How to create a schema to describe "jobs".
4. How to create and execute a "job" from the schema.

Marry all these together and you'll answer your own question.

Computer science is about decomposition: breaking large problems into smaller ones that you can handle.  I'd recommend taking that approach here.